# Requests getting failed with error 400 when thread count increased in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

.net application starts giving error  http 400(bad request) when 200 concurrent users are loaded.
And while running script, when application is browsed manually, could able to see same errors. This basically rules out, its not client issue.
So What is causing this error?
Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't know but it sounds like an application bug in any case because HTTP status codes 4xx are [client errors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#Client_error_responses) and given it occurs only under the load the application should respond with [5xx server error codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#Server_error_responses)

You need to inspect your application/webserver/loadbalancer logs as most probably the cause can be figured out from them.

Also it would be a good idea to check whether your application has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, etc as the errors could be caused by simple lack of resources. You can use i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)  for this